# list to csv format using python

Tags: python, csv

```
a = [{'year': 222, 'title': 'abc'}, {'year': 111, 'title': 'ddd'}]
```

how can i convert to csv format like

```
b =     year, title
        222, abc
        111, ddd
```

I use aws lambda that I can't import pandas

Comment: Why do you need pandas? `import csv`...

Comment: Also, this is basically  a dupe of your last question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49423634/json-to-csv-using-python

Comment: what is your "a dupe" meaning? I'm a dupe of python using I admit. Just I want to learn more about python and ask too simple question?

Comment: "I use aws lambda that I can't import pandas", means I don't want import pandas. Why you still ask me"Why do you need pandas?", So Funny?

Comment: **Dup**-licate. And what I meant was why you you think you **need** pandas? When there are other ways to write a CSV without external libraries.

Comment: And you can definitely try to package external Python libraries such as pandas by following. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-python-how-to-create-deployment-package.html

Answer (score 2):

Use [csv.dictwriter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictWriter)

```
import csv
import io


a = [{'year': 222, 'title': 'abc'}, {'year': 111, 'title': 'ddd'}]
f = io.StringIO()
fieldnames = ['year', 'title']
writer = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames=fieldnames)
writer.writeheader()
for d in a:
    writer.writerow(d)

print(f.getvalue())

out:
year,title
222,abc
111,ddd
```

Comment: Sorry, I using aws lambda cann't use"with open('names.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:", Can you help me ?

Comment: obj = s3.get_object(Bucket='excelfile23987', Key='ttttt.json')<br>
    body = obj['Body']<br>
    a = body.read().decode('utf-8')<br>
    # [{'year': 222, 'title': 'abc'}, {'year': 111, 'title': 'ddd'}]

Comment: my original "a"resource is show above. I have an error in"writer.writerow(d)".   "errorMessage": "'str' object has no attribute 'keys'", "errorType": "AttributeError",Please help me

Comment: Don't ask multiple question. I have answered your question. then you told you cant use file. I changed my answer. Now you want another answer.

Comment: Sorry..because I consider that cut down some useless code. And the action produce this problem. It's okay. Thank you very much answered me two time already.